Why Do libdispatch Macros Appear Empty in `_dispatch_client_callout`?
I am reading the source code of libdispatch and came across the implementation of the _dispatch_client_callout function as follows:
#define _dispatch_get_tsd_base()
#define _dispatch_get_unwind_tsd() (NULL)
#define _dispatch_set_unwind_tsd(u) do {(void)(u);} while (0)
#define _dispatch_free_unwind_tsd()

#define likely(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
#define unlikely(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)

void
_dispatch_client_callout(void *ctxt, dispatch_function_t f)
{
    _dispatch_get_tsd_base();
    void *u = _dispatch_get_unwind_tsd();
    if (likely(!u)) return f(ctxt);
    _dispatch_set_unwind_tsd(NULL);
    f(ctxt);
    _dispatch_free_unwind_tsd();
    _dispatch_set_unwind_tsd(u);
}

In the _dispatch_client_callout function, a series of macros are invoked, but these macros seem to have empty implementations, such as:
#define _dispatch_get_tsd_base()
#define _dispatch_get_unwind_tsd() (NULL)
#define _dispatch_set_unwind_tsd(u) do {(void)(u);} while (0)
#define _dispatch_free_unwind_tsd()

Why is this the case? What should the actual implementations of these macros look like?

The lines above the code snippet explain their rationale: “On platforms with SjLj exceptions, avoid the SjLj overhead on every callout by clearing the unwinder's TSD pointer to the handler stack around callouts”. I believe that this SjLj (Setjmp/Longjmp) optimization of the TSD (thread-safe data) pointer is not needed for modern hardware. The NOOPs are a conscious decision, not some omission.
